# Pandas: How to Create Frequency Distribution of Elements Ocurring in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency

I have a Pandas dataframe with three columns: sentence, key phrases, category.
The key phrases column contains either an empty list or words/phrases from the sentence row it comes from, like so:

| Sentence | Key Phrases | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| the red ball | `['red ball']` | object |
| a big blue box | `['blue']` | object |
| he throws the red ball | `['he throws','red ball']` | action |

I want to check the contents of the entire **key phrases** column and build a frequency dictionary (or whatever is best) for every unique phrase. So in my example I'd have something like: `'red ball': 2, 'blue': 1, 'he throws': 1`

Then I want to calculate the frequency distribution of these key phrases across all categories in the data frame. So in my example, **object** category is 100% of *'blue'* ocurrences, but only 50% of *'red ball'*. I am assuming the best way to do this is starting with the frequency dictionary I mentioned above?

Finally, I'd like to add another column to the dataframe which will show, for each key phrase in its row, what percentage of that key phrase's occurences exist within that category.

So the final DF would look something like this, though the aesthetic doesnt matter as long as the information is there:

| Sentence | Key Phrases | Category | Key Phrase Ocurrences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| the red ball | `['red ball']` | object | red ball: 50% |
| a big blue box | `['blue']` | object | blue: 100% |
| he throws the red ball | `['he throws', 'red ball']` | action | he throws: 100%, red ball: 50% |

It would also be useful to have something like a dictionary where each key was the category and each value contained all the key phrases occurring within that category and their prevalence, so maybe this would be in the initial dictionary I'd create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we explode the df so we have line by line Key Phrases:

```
df2 = df.explode('Key Phrases')
df2
```

output:

```
    Sentence                Key Phrases Category
0   the red ball            red ball    object
1   a big blue box          blue        object
2   he throws the red ball  he throws   action
2   he throws the red ball  red ball    action
```

Then we create a table of occurrences as such:

```
df3 = df2.groupby(['Key Phrases','Category'])['Sentence'].count().unstack().fillna(0)
df3
```

output:

```
Category    action  object
Key Phrases     
blue        0.0     1.0
he throws   1.0     0.0
red ball    1.0     1.0
```

Then we convert into frequencies by dividing occurrences by totals

```
df4 = df3.apply(lambda c: c/df3.sum(axis=1))
df4
```

output:

```
Category    action  object
Key Phrases     
blue        0.0     1.0
he throws   1.0     0.0
red ball    0.5     0.5
```

This answers part 1 of your question

to fit it back to the original data, we can do the following. it is easier to do it to the already-exploded version, the dataframe `df2`:

```
df2.merge(df4.unstack().rename('freq').reset_index(), how = 'left', on = ['Category', 'Key Phrases'])
```

output:

```
    Sentence                Key Phrases    Category      freq
--  ----------------------  -------------  ----------  ------
 0  the red ball            red ball       object         0.5
 1  a big blue box          blue           object         1
 2  he throws the red ball  he throws      action         1
 3  he throws the red ball  red ball       action         0.5
```

this has all the info you would like to see although admittedly not in quite a pretty format. as you said the format did not matter so much I will leave it here but you can always do further `groupby`s etc

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
df['Key Phrase Ocurrences'] = 100 * df.nunique(axis = 1)/df.count(axis = 1)
```

Comment: that looks quite efficient but it doesnt take into consideration that **key phrases** can contain multiple elements in the list. so the final row in my table contains two elements in the **key phrases** column and id want a rate of occurrence for each phrase, not the full list.